# Blazor Server: EditForm not calling submit method or validation

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Within my Blazor Server Project I have the following code:

***Form.razor:***

```
@using AVA.ZICHT.WEBSITE.Data.Models

@page "/form"

<div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

    <EditForm Model="@_subscribeCommand" OnValidSubmit="SubmitSubscribe">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <div class="form-group">
            <InputText @bind-Value="@_subscribeCommand.Email" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Vul hier jouw e-mailadres in..." />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => _subscribeCommand.Email" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary mt-2">Aanmelden</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    private SubscribeCommand _subscribeCommand = new();

    private void SubmitSubscribe()
    {
        Snackbar.Add("Valid submit!...", Severity.Success);
    }
}
```

***SubscribeCommand.cs (model):***

```
public class SubscribeCommand
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email must be valid.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

When I am using the form I have the following issues:

- I receive no validation errors. "lorem ipsum" should receive invalid email error.
- Leaving the input empty and submitting is not receiving required validation error.
- Hitting the submit button goes to the URL "/?" instead of calling the OnValidSubmit method

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Blazor Server in .NET 7

Comment: Can you post a minimum reproducible example? My example using the majority of your code works fine: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/4exvoogn.

Answer (score 0):

As I checked your code it is working fine but you forgot to include NameSpaces May be in your razor form please check

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in my question was not the source of the problem. I created a new Blazor Server Project and the problem was solved.

Probably a problem with setup of project or I accidentally removed some lines of code somewhere...